# Results of running two subqueries do not add up to the number of results when running the main query

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jql, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am running a JQL query to count how many issues have an empty value for the "Components" field versus how many issues have a non empty value for the "Components" field.

Here is the screenshot that I get for my 1st JQL query: `category = "Cloud Services"  and component is empty`, the number of results is 6631:
[image]
Checking for null is equivalent to checling for empty, I have tried it and it returns the same.

Here is the screenshot for my 2nd JQL query: `category = "Cloud Services"  and component is not empty`
[image]

The thing that confuses me is that I get 6631 results for my first query and I get 51372 results for my second result so 51372 +6631 = 58003

However, when I try to retrieve all the issues belonging to the Cloud Services category with this query: `category = "Cloud Services"`, I get the following: I get 64879 as a result which does not match 51372 +6631 = 58003 computed above. Anyone knows why? Normally, the total number should correspond to the result of the 3rd screenshot since every issue contains components.
[image]

Comment: null is the same as empty, the 2 queries are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this only means, you have in the project more than 1 component, that is why the adds dont match.

with the REST api you can verify howmany and which components you have:

```
https://<host>/rest/api/latest/project/<project_id>/components
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also be that one of the projects has a field configuration with the Components field hidden?